# Passing a token securely from one controller method to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, token

I want to generate a random token for my user. For UX reasons, I want to generate this token in `MyController#new` in order to show it in `new` view. Then I need to pass it to `create` method. However, I want to prevent user from changing it.

I know of 3 ways to do it:

1. pass it as hidden field
2. pass it through sessions
3. write it to database, marked as incomplete, then set it to complete in `create method`

The first two approaches are not secure, while the last is overkill.

Is there a way to securely pass a parameter from `new` to `create` method in controller?

Comment: I think session is secure enough. Or you can use a memory-based cache system, such as memcached. Store token with user's id, and then retrieve token back using user's id.

Comment: Tanks Bigxiang. Could you kindly create an answer that details your solution for Rails 4? I have very limited understanding of securing session in Rails 4.

Comment: Hi, I saw dexter had created an answer, I'm off now, I will review the question in the evening if you still have question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions in Rails and # and above are very very secure because they are hashed. The official library says there are no practically evidences of session hash been compromised so the user can only delete that token from the browser but they can't change it to a logically correct value.

What you can do is save the value in sessions and make a hash value yourself from that token and save it also in session then on the receiving side you can regenerate the hash from the session and verify the value.

no user can edit both the session values that they match. If its not matching you can discard the values and throw to an error page.

I hope i answered you, if there is any misunderstanding pls ask.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Could you give an example of how I would do that?

Comment: suppose you have the parameter in a variable as `pass` now you can encrypt it like this `Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(pass)` and save this also in the session.

Comment: on the other side means in the other action, create this hash again from the `pass` and if it matches then it means no change has been done to your `pass` or token.

Comment: Hi dirtydexter, how do I get back the content of `pass` in `#create` method? I need this token and not just the encripted value.

Comment: ah, beside doing that, I also create another hash and compare value. Thanks.

Comment: when you pass it pass it like `session[:pass]=pass` and `session[:hash]=Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(pass)` then in `#create` you can retrieve it like `session[:pass]` and match condition will be `if session[:hash] == Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(session[:pass])`